# Why jetty transformed certificate subject parameter S to ST?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, ssl-certificate

I'm using certificate with subject

```
CN = operator-1505
O = Test org
L = Moscow
S = Moscow
C = RU
```

But when I'm trying to get this certificate in my servlet:

```
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        if (certificates != null && certificates.length == 1) {
            X509Certificate certificate = certificates[0];
            authenticate(certificate, req, resp);
        }
    }
```

Subject in `certificate` variable is:

```
CN=operator-1505, O=Test org, L=Moscow, ST=Moscow, C=RU
```

Why jetty transformed S parameter to ST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `S` (or `ST`) isn't really in the certificate.  What it contains is the Object Identifier (OID) [2.5.4.8](http://www.oid-info.com/get/2.5.4.8).

OpenSSL used to have [a snarky comment](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/ae5c8664e587f2445c8e4eb436cffbb64af4f6b8/crypto/objects/objects.h#L149) saying that an authoritative answer for the short form of this OID is "ST", but that Microsoft used "S".

It's probably the case that two different RFCs referenced the same OID with different short forms, and each library just ends up with its own answer for what to use for that particular value.

If you can print the name using OID values that should be stable across environments, but otherwise you may just have to come up with a way to match on `S=` or `ST=`.

**Edit**: I'm amused to note that [ITU-T X.520](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.520-201210-S) (2012/10) says that "ST" is the correct answer, while using S= as an example:

> 6.3.3 State or Province Name
>
> The State or Province Name attribute type specifies a state or province. When used as a component of a directory name, it identifies a geographical subdivision in which the named object is physically located or with which it is associated in some other important way.
>
> An attribute value for State or Province Name is a string, e.g., **S = "Ohio"**
>
> ```
> stateOrProvinceName ATTRIBUTE ::= {
>   SUBTYPE OF name
>   WITH SYNTAX UnboundedDirectoryString
>   LDAP-SYNTAX directoryString.&id
>   LDAP-NAME {"st"}
>   ID id-at-stateOrProvinceName }
> ```

(emphasis mine, and sadly I can't have the "**LDAP-NAME {"st"}**" both emphasized and whitespace-preserving)