# Unsupperted ST tag in UWP Identity Publisher

Tags: uwp, certificate

I need to sign an UWP app for side-loading. Our app signing certificate has the following part in the Subject along with other fields:

ST=statename

If I set the Subject as the Identity / Publisher in my AppxManifest.xml I get a "The 'Publisher' attribute is invalid" error in Visual Studio and I cannot build my app.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-identity, the ST tag is not accepted in the Publisher field.

It violates the following pattern:

```
'(CN|L|O|OU|E|C|S|STREET|T|G|I|SN|DC|SERIALNUMBER|Description|PostalCode|POBox|Phone|X21Address|dnQualifier|(OID\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))+))=(([^,+="<>#;])+|".*")(, ((CN|L|O|OU|E|C|S|STREET|T|G|I|SN|DC|SERIALNUMBER|Description|PostalCode|POBox|Phone|X21Address|dnQualifier|(OID\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*))+))=(([^,+="<>#;])+|".*")))*'
```

Is there a way around this without purchasing another certificate?

Update:
I've found the ST tag mentioned in other documentations and it seems valid to be included in the Subject.

- https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-appx-publisher-id.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/distinguished-names

Comment: 'ST' from OpenSSL is 'S' from Windows (and neither is actually in the cert, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210039/why-jetty-transformed-certificate-subject-parameter-s-to-st/43211218#43211218), so there must be something else that the tooling is upset about.

Comment: I open the certificate in Azure Key Vault and I see the ST=... tag in the Subject. I assumed I have to copy the whole thing from there and use it as the Publisher.... and that didn't work so far. But I'll try to use S in the UWP app and see what happens.

Comment: Well, I still get an error no matter I use S, ST or OID.2.5.4.8 in my UWP app. I am able to build the app with S, but then I get an error that the Publisher is not the same as the Subject in the certificate.

Comment: @hthms try SERIALNUMBER instead.

Comment: @PakUula what do you mean by this? The subject in my certificate has no SERIALNUMBER field. Do you suggest putting the state info into the SERIALNUMBER?

Comment: @hthms the regular expression from MS supports SERIALNUMBER. Check the serial number of your certificate. E.g. the certificate that Stackoverflow uses for https has serial number `03bdbed66faa3382b582d0cc3758d1d8525b`, and the corresponding string wuold be `SERIALNUMBER=03bdbed66faa3382b582d0cc3758d1d8525b`

Comment: @PakUula If I set SERIALNUMBER=... in my Publisher field then I still get the error "The Publisher Identity in the AppxManifest.xml does not match the subject on the certificate for file".
It seems to me that the only option is to request a new certificate without the S or ST tag...